# How to combine last element with first element of two ndarray with different shapes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy arrays, like this (example):

```
array1 = ['a','b','c']

array2 = ['d','e']
```

and I want one array like this:

`final_array = ['a','b','cd','e']` --> the last element of `array1` is concatenated with first element of `array2`

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings and character arrays are not numpy's strongest suit, but it can be done:

```
>>> np.r_[array1[:-1], [array1[-1]+array2[0]], array2[1:]]
array(['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e'], dtype='<U2')
```

or

```
>>> np.concatenate([array1[:-1], [array1[-1]+array2[0]], array2[1:]])
array(['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e'], dtype='<U2')
```